# How to use subtotal function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using subtotal function in cell F1 and G1 but getting zero value so please help me to find out the reason of this error and is there any way to get the sum of filtered data in last row after applying the filter via slicer dialogue box i.e. sectors and date.
thank you.

[image]

Comment: You are only grabbing the header: `=SUBTOTAL(9,Table3[GAIN IN AUC])`

Comment: thank you its working but how can i get this value below the last row

Comment: You can add a total row to the table.  In the Table Design Tab select Total Row.